# how to delete deploy/images/beaglebone dir in yocto

Tags: yocto, build-system

In my yocto source `deploy/images/beaglebone` dir is nearly 100GB so i want to free that memory

Please help me how can I delete that deploy dir either manually or via command line

```
I want to clean all images(*.tar.gz,*.sdcard, *.ubifs) of previous compilation in yocto deploy/images/beaglebone/
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe when you are with 100GB in the deploy directory, things have gone too far already.

Check your **IMAGE_FSTYPES** variable. My experience says it is safe to delete all images of these files that are not symlinks, or symlinks targets. Avoid the last one generated to avoid breaking the last build link, and any related with bootloaders and configuration files, as they could be rarely regenerated.

If you are keeping more than one build with the same set of layers, then you can use a common download folder for builds.

> DL_DIR ?= "common_dir_across_all_builds/downloads/"

And afterwards:

To keep your /deploy clean:

> **RM_OLD_IMAGE:** Reclaims disk space by removing previously built versions of the same image from the images directory pointed to by the DEPLOY_DIR variable.Set this variable to "1" in your local.conf file to remove these images:
>
> `RM_OLD_IMAGE = "1"`
>
> **IMAGE_FSTYPES** Remove the image types that you do not plan to use, you can always enable a particular one when you need it:
>
> `IMAGE_FSTYPES_remove = "tar.bz2"`
>
> `IMAGE_FSTYPES_remove = "rpi-sdimg"`
>
> `IMAGE_FSTYPES_remove = "ext3"`

For /tmp/work, do not need all the workfiles of all recipes. You can specify which ones you are interested in your development.

> **RM_WORK_EXCLUDE**:
>       With rm_work enabled, this variable specifies a list of recipes whose work directories should not be removed. See the "rm_work.bbclass" section for more details.
>
> `INHERIT += "rm_work"`
>
> `RM_WORK_EXCLUDE += "home-assistant widde"`

Comment: Dear @urnenfeld Thanks for your reply. when i use RM_OLD_IMAGE it is deleting last modified  images only not all images previously compiled more times. so i want to clean all images not only last one. Please suggest anything else. Thanks you.

Comment: Yes unfortunately, all done before you set this option would need to be deleted manually. Note all these options go to your conf/loca.conf

Comment: yes that is only i mentioned in my answer but is there any alternative @urnenfeld.

Comment: Dear @urnenfeld, I have manually deleted only rootfs files ( *.tar.gz and *.sdcard,*.ext*) not other files. but make sure dont delete recently compiled rootfs(that you can find when use ls -l command soft link will show you)

Comment: Jul 20 15:52 tke-its-box-image-ITS_Box.emmc -> tke-its-box-image-ITS_Box-20170720101808.rootfs.emmc
Jul 20 15:52 tke-its-box-image-ITS_Box.ext4 -> tke-its-box-image-ITS_Box-20170720101808.rootfs.ext4                                                                                         Note: above are softlinks of last compiled RFS. make sure dont delete .cfg files

Comment: @VadalasettiSivanageswararao Godd sugestion! I edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

try this from your build root `rm -fr deploy/images`. [Here](https://community.nxp.com/thread/353311) is a good discussion on the topic

Comment: Thanks @tony, inside the images dir one readme is there. that is telling dont delete the files manually.so what to do?

Comment: If you want to free HDD space, rm -rf tmp folder. The tmp folder is ~temporary~ and will be recreated during next build

Comment: Dear tony i have tried your link and i removed rm -rf /build/deploy/images   now its giving error.

Comment: If the deploy dir is removed, I would "bitbake image -c cleanall" & maybe remove as well the ${WORKDIR} of the image's recipe(at least). By this way, maybe the bootfiles are as well re-generated

Comment: @VadalasettiSivanageswararao glad it helped you

Answer (score 1):

```
I just removed the files manually like below
1. goto build/deploy/images/beaglebone

2. $ ll : you will find the softlinks of rootfs with time like
......*20170811091521.rootfs.tar.gz
......*-20170811091521.rootfs.sdcard etc
3. Dont delete recently compiled files. except these this you can remove all *.tar.gz, *.sdcard,*.ext4 manually like below,

4. rm beaglebone-20170811091521.rootfs.tar.gz
   rm beaglebone-20170811091521.rootfs.sdcard
   rm beaglebone-20170811091521.rootfs.ext4    etc.
```